# How to know if TYPO3 extensions flux and fluidcontent are used?

Tags: typo3, typo3-7.6.x, tx-fluidcontent

I am maintaining a TYPO3 installation using `7.6.11` and there are the extensions `flux` and `fluidcontent` installed. How can I quickly check if those are really used?

Comment: Just an FYI for future users... `fluidcontent` is deprecated now and there's migration info to `flux` here https://github.com/FluidTYPO3/flux/issues/1542

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use the extension [additional_reports](https://typo3.org/extensions/repository/view/additional_reports) to get an overview about all used ContentElements. 
also have a look in the list of available ContenteElement types. are there more than the usual?

Comment: I just wanted to +1 this solution with words: short of manually writing SQL queries to scan for plugin instances `additional_reports` is *the* easiest way to scan for any plugin instance types and is particularly useful during TYPO3 upgrades which require many extension upgrades.